# Facing this since 1 week - everything was working fine before & no code changes have been effected

Tags: php, mysql, apache, exception, shopify

Everything was working fine - now since last week - this pops up whenever we try to authenticate and get a token to start proceeding.

Could not resolve host: yogafunforall.myshopify.com; Unknown error#0 /home/unitexpr/public_html/app/client.php(47): ShopifyClient->curlHttpApiRequest('POST', 'https://yogafun...', '', 'client_id=e39e0...', Array) #1 /home/unitexpr/public_html/app/install.php(90): ShopifyClient->getAccessToken('3dfa74da9f1cbf0...') #2 {main}

1. Code - nominal - client side [html/css]
2. server side / api / library - no code change
3. updates - same php / mysql / apache stack and server side no changes either

Hosting Support: "error is not related to us as no changes on the server have been effected since the error occurred."
Shopify Support: "since a 3rd party library is being used, we cannot solve the error related to the same, since the error has started occurring there have been no TOKEN/AUTH requests received on our servers, hence the problem is in your application"

I have just taken up the project for support - its been live and running since a year now. Besides handling support tickets, adding some basic features or modifications to client side bugs, speeding up etc I have no experience with the code but its not that difficult.

I am clueless as to what can throw this exception to a perfectly running project.

Comment: Since it’s a DNS problem it’s either the DNS the server is using or the DNS handling that (sub)domain. So one of the people you already contacted should be responsible and it has nothing to do with code or libraries.

Comment: Thank you - appreciate your prompt and to the point reply, I have raised the question with the Shopify support team & also my domain provider, hope they can generate a reasonable response this time. I will update progress in the meantime still testing.

Comment: I need a way to identify the problem is from SHOPIFY auth process / as their stores are sub-domains - however they can simply throw the support request by saying we have not received auth requests....

Comment: They won’t receive since it’s an DNS issue. Since that host resolved properly for me the issue should be at the hosting side. They can’t find the host -> no requests go anywhere.

Comment: The hosting server reply:    "Our DNS servers are as follows:

Primary: [IP]
Secondary: {IP}

From there error it looks likes it can not resolve the host name of eklips.myshopify.com it could be that hostname does not exist which is why it does not resolve"

now the eklips.myshopify.com hostname is real and redirects to the relevant customer store or shopify to signup -                                                        where do i verify the above DNS entries....?

Comment: BIND service status is a failure permanently - does not restart - gives [Job for named.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status named.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.]  & [ Oct 21 20:23:48 s103642.wholesaleinternet.net bash[32171]: /etc/named.conf:68: zone '': is not a valid name
Oct 21 20:23:48 s103642.wholesaleinternet.net bash[32171]: /etc/named.conf:69: zone '': is not a valid name]